# Store 2D array (String) to file and retrieve it

Tags: java, arrays, object, syntax, 2d

I have made a simple program that has a 2D String array storing lots of data. I have searched a lot of places for how to store and retrieve 2D arrays. I want to save the data in my array at the end of the program and have this data retrieved upon the start of the program. I have tried:
 `ObjectOutputStream toFile = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("array.DATA"));
            toFile.writeObject(array);` This came up with the error: incompatible types: FileWriter cannot be converted to OutputStream

I only know basic programming so try to be easy on me and explain everything you say thoroughly. If I'm honest I don't even know what 'ObjectOutputStream' is.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You have to wait a little bit i will show you full code example!

Answer (score 2):

In this example:
  This example is very simple(**it's not a perfect solution but it's a good start to undestand how save and retrieve works**).

Your 2d array is  int a[][]= new int[12][12];

//or a is String a[][] = new String[12][12];

- Part 1: (Save)

  ```
  public void Save(){

   try {
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/Users/Alex.hp/Desktop/t.txt"));

      for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
          for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){

            //use this if your array has (int,double..)
                // writer.write(String.valueOf(a[i][j])+" "); //Here you parse the int from array to String.


             //use this if your array has String
               writer.write(a[i][j]+" "); //Its String so you dont have to use String.valueOf(something(int,double,...)
          }
         writer.println(); //leave one line 
      }

      writer.flush();  //flush the writer
      writer.close();  //close the writer      



     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {      
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
  ```

  }//end of method

**Using a simple PrintWriter you save your array into a file exaclty how it is.**
*Just you know change the path i have put to the file;*

- Part 2: (Update or Retrieve on Open)

  ```
  public void UpdateOnOpen(){

   try {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Alex.hp/Desktop/t.txt"));

  //Retrieve
          for(int i=0; i<a.length;  i++)
            for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){

            //if you array use (int,double,...)
              //a[i][j]=Interger.parseInt(scan.next()) //for int
              //a[i][j]=Double.parseDouble(scan.next()) //for double

            //if your array use String
              a[i][j]=scan.next(); //Here you retrieve the array again from the file


            }//end of for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++)



       scan.close(); //close the resource file you opened

  //Print it to be sure all are right
            for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
                  for(int c=0; c<a[i].length; c++)
                        System.out.printf(""+a[i][c]+",");

              System.out.println();    
            }                         

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){  e.printStackTrace(); }    


  }//end of method
  ```

  **Using Scanner class you retrieve your array back from the file saved.**

Also a better solution but you have to dig more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751273/how-to-store-data-in-java-database)

Let me know it your job is done..

Comment: Thanks. How do you retrieve the info into the array? And does this work for String? And what does e.printStackTrace(); do? @crAlex

Comment: yes it work for String. I will transform it. e.printStackTrace() just print the problem in the console if it catch a problem.

Comment: I get the error cannot find symbol after I pasted the method and compiled. I get this for my array variable

Comment: your array usE String or int?

Comment: I've solved the error. All i need now is how to retrieve the file data into the array at the start of the program

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional question to resolve, which is how do you store the sizes of the arrays as well as the contents. I would recommend using conversion to JSON. If you get the Jackson library, you should be able to use the Jackson Object Mapper. I would recommend storing your arrays within another object.

e.g.

```
class MyClass {
    String[][] myArray;

    // add the getters and setters to this class for myArray too
}
```

Then for storing

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();

// set the arrays here to whatever you like

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.write(new File("c:\somedir\somefile.txt"), myObject);
```

Then for loading

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass loaded = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\somedir\somefile.txt", MyClass.class);

// then you can use loaded as the source of your data
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using FileOutputStream instead. FileWriter in character while ObjectOutputStream is binary output stream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream toFile = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("//home//user//array.DATA"));
        toFile.writeObject(args);
        toFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respone @RockSolid Can you tell me what each part of the code you have provided does?

Comment: I also need to know how to retrieve the file

Comment: Try simple copy paste the program and run this (program args 1 2 3 4 5) For reading Use ObjectInputStream.FileInputStream and readObject