# JAVA: How can I read a text file and store the data into an array if I know how many numbers are in the text file?

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

I have a text file that looks like this:

14 (*THIS IS THE NUMBER OF LINES OF NUMBERS WHICH FOLLOW)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14

Now I need to use a for loop to read this data using Scanner and then store the numbers (except the first line) in an array.

I have this so far but I'm stuck:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DirectoryLookupApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(new File("Data3.txt"));
   int numTimes = dataFile.nextInt(); //since the first line tells us how many numbers are in the file-how many times loop will run
   int dataText = new int [numTimes];   
 }
}
```

Comment: The text file is separated by a new line - so each number is on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

so you would want a for loop that does 14 reads which would be like:

```
for (i = 0; i < numTimes; i++)
{
    dataText[i] = dataFile.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Approved the edit, but to OP that means you need to set up dataText as an array if you want to use it like this.  So like:

int[] dataText = new int[numTimes]

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question from yesterday(the code in my answer is already tested if it works..) you can transform it as you want.

[Store 2D array (String) to file and retrieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516417/store-2d-array-string-to-file-and-retrieve-it/28516775#28516775)