# How can I make my matrix multiplication Java code more fail-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

I am working on a project, where I was provided a Java  matrix-multiplication  program which can run in a distributed system , which is run like so :

```
usage: java Coordinator maxtrix-dim number-nodes coordinator-port-num
```

For example:

```
java blockMatrixMultiplication.Coordinator 25  25 54545
```

Here's a snapshot of how output looks like :

[image]

I want to extend this code with some kind of failsafe ability - and  am curious about how I would create checkpoints within a running matrix multiplication calculation. The general idea is to  recover to where it was in a computation (but it doesn't need to be so fine grained - just recover to beginning, i.e `row 0 column 0` )

My first idea is to use log files (like Apache log4j ), where I would be logging the relevant matrix status. Then, if we forcibly shut down the app in the middle of a calculation, we could recover to a reasonable checkpoint.

Should I use MySQL for such a task (or maybe a more lightweight database)? Or would a basic log file ( and using some useful Apache libraries) be good enough ?  any tips appreciated, thanks

source-code :

[MatrixMultiple](http://pastebin.com/HeMqN2g1)

[Coordinator](http://pastebin.com/zuuaxETf)

[Connection](http://pastebin.com/ebjZ7qwJ)

[DataIO](http://pastebin.com/i1yPi966)

[Worker](http://pastebin.com/AWhK56yd)

Comment: Suggest you look into the topic "Java Persistence". There are a number of options in this area. Two I'm familiar with are "JPA" (Java Persistence API) and "Hibernate".  Basically they are mechanisms to 'persist' Java objects into/from a database.  Seems like they could do a lot of the heavy lifting in a checkpointing mechanism.

Comment: @JohnHascall - Ok , I'll study up on Java Persistence & Hibernate.  so it probably wouldn't be wise if I tried to manually create log files , and using these libraries would help. thanks  very much!

Comment: I was curious about whether JMX might help here ?

Comment: Just to clarify, all you need to do is recover two matrixes when the program starts up and multiply them, given that the program crashed or was closed before the problem was solved on the previous run, or do you need to recover the whole session including problems which have already been solved?

Comment: @rp.beltran  -  I need to look into it some more myself , but I believe i'd prefer to recover as close as possible to the point-of-crash .  So if we crashed while multiplying a 7 X 7 matrix with another 7 X 7 matrix, and we were on matrix cell `[3, 4]`, then perhaps we'd recover to `[3, 0 ]`   (i.e create a checkpoint at beginning of new row. )

Comment: I just noticed that in the `MatrixMultiple` class, they are using Math.random .  I am not sure, but maybe this prevents us from doing this checkpoint idea

Comment: Looking at it, I think random is only used in the `main(String[] args)` method to generate an example matrix for testing. The process of solving the problem seems to be handled deterministically.

Comment: @rp.beltran - Ok , I see what you mean now, so it should be possible to recover the matrix.  thanks !

Comment: @rp.beltran - going back to your previous question, we would only be concerned about the previous run ( not any of previous sessions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, all you need to do is recover your place in a single matrix calculation in the event of a crash or if the application is quit half way through.

## Minimum Viable Solution

The simplest approach would be to recover just the two matrixes you were actively multiplying, but none of your progress, and multiply them from the beginning next time you load the application.

The Process:

1. At the beginning of `public static int[][] multiplyMatrix(int[][] a, int[][] b)` in your `MatrixMultiple` class, create a file, let's call it `recovery_data.txt` with the state of the two arrays being multiplied (parameters `a` and `b`). Alternatively, you could use a simple database for this.
2. At the end of `public static int[][] multiplyMatrix(int[][] a, int[][] b)` in your `MatrixMultiple` class, right before you return, clear the contents of the file, or wipe you database.
3. When the program is initially run, most likely near the beginning of the `main(String[] args)` you should check to see if the contents of the text file is non-null, in which case you should multiply the contents of the file, and display the output, otherwise proceed as usual.

Notes on implementation:

- Using a simple text file or a full fledged relational database is a decision you are going to have to make, mostly based on the real world data that only you could really know, but in my mind, a textile wins out in most situations, and here are my reasons why. You are going to want to read the data sequentially to rebuild your matrix, and so being relational is not that useful. Databases are harder to work with, not too hard, but compared to a text file there is no question, and since you would not be much use of querying, that isn't balanced out by the ways they usually might make a programmers life easier.
- Consider how you are going to store your arrays. In a text file, you have several options, my recommendation would be to store each row in a line of text, separated by spaces or commas, or some other character, and then put an extra line of blank space before the second matrix. I think a similar approach is used in [crAlexander's Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516417/store-2d-array-string-to-file-and-retrieve-it), but I have not tested his code. Alternatively, you could use something more complicated like JSON, but I think that would be too heavy handed to justify. If you are using a database, then the relational structure should make several logical arrangements for your data apparent as well.

## Strategic Checkpoints

You expressed interest in saving some calculations by taking advantage of the possibility that some of the calculations will have already been handled on last time the program ran. Lets look first look at the Pros and Cons of adding in checkpoints after every row has been processed, best I can see them.

Pros:

- Save computation time next time the program is run, if the system had been closed.

Cons:

- Making the extra writes will either use more nodes if distributed (more on that later) or increase general latency from calculations because you now have to throw in a database write operation for every checkpoint
- More complicated to implement (but probably not by too much)
- If my comments on the implementation of the Minimum Viable Solution about being able to get away with a text file convinced you that you would not have to add in RDBMS, I take back the parts about not leveraging queries, and everything being accessed sequentially, so a database is now perhaps a smarter choice.

I'm not saying that checkpoints are definitely not the better solution, just that I don't know if they are worth it, but here is what I would consider:

- Do you expect people to be quitting half way through a calculation frequently relative to the total amount of calculations they will be running? If you think this feature will be used a lot, then the pro of adding checkpoints becomes much more significant relative to the con of it slowing down calculations as a whole.
- Does it take a long time to complete a typical calculation that people are providing the program? If so, the added latency I mentioned in the cons is (percentage wise) smaller, and so perhaps more tolerable, but users are already less happy with performance, and so that cancels out some of the effect there. It also makes the argument for checkpointing more significant because it has the potential to save more time.

And so I would only recommend checkpointing like this if you expect a relatively large amount of instances where this is happening, and if it takes a relatively large amount of time to complete a calculation.

If you decide to go with checkpoints, then modify the approach to:

- after every row has been processed on the array that you produce the content of that row to your database, or if you use the textile, at the end of the textile, after another empty line to separate it from the last matrix.
- on startup if you need to finish a calculation that has already been begun, solve out and distribute only the rows that have yet to be considered, and retrieve the content of the other rows from your database.

*A quick point on implementing frequent checkpoints:* You could greatly reduce the extra latency from adding in frequent checkpoints by pushing this task out to an additional thread. Doing this would use more processes, and there is always some latency in actually spawning the process or thread, but you do not have to wait for the entire write operation to be completed before proceeding.

## A quick warning on the implementation of any such failsafe method

If there is an unchecked edge case that would mean some sort of invalid matrix would crash the program, this failsafe now bricks the program it entirely by trying it again on every start. To combat this, I see some obvious solutions, but perhaps a bit of thought would let you modify my approaches to something you prefer:

- Use a lot of try and catch statements, if you get any sort of error that seems to be caused by malformed data, wipe your recovery file, or modify it to add a note that tells your program to treat it as a special case. A good treatment of this special case may be to display the two matrixes at start with an explanation that your program failed to multiply them likely due to malformed content.
- Add data in your file/database on how many times the program has quit while solving the current problem, if this is not the first resume, treat it like the special case in the above option.

I hope that this provided enough information for you to implement your failsafe in the way that makes the most sense given what you suspect the realistic use to be, and note that there are perhaps other ways you could approach this problem as well, and these could equally have their own lists of pros and cons to take into consideration.

Comment: Thank you very much rp.beltran !  I will be studying this, and I'm definitely interested in using threads to offload some of the checkpoint processing